# getting error while starting a new spring starter project in sts 3.6.0

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, web-services, windows-7, spring-tool-suite

I have installed sts 3.6.0 in Windows 7 32bit system with intel pentium dual core processor. While creating a new spring starter project for the first time i am getting an error called FileNoFoundException. The error pop-up mentions "Note that this wizard uses a webservice and needs internet access. A more detailed error message may be found in the Eclipse error log".  am using internet through WI-FI but still this error is coming. Please provide me a solution for this. [image]

Comment: You are sure you have internet access? Have you tried to call the url in your browser?

Comment: Yes i have internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Tool Suite 3.6.0 was [released over 6 years ago](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/11/spring-tool-suite-and-groovy-grails-tool-suite-3-6-0-released). Things have moved on a bit since then and, as a result, it's trying to call an endpoint on https://start/spring.io that does not exist. Upgrading to a newer version of STS will fix your problem. If you need a 32-bit version, you'll need to stick with STS 3.x. You can find download links for the latest 3.x version [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/toolsuite-distribution/wiki/Spring-Tool-Suite-3#latest-sts3-downloads).

Comment: The latest version of STS 3.x for Windows 32bit was STS 3.9.9, you can get it from here: https://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.9.9.RELEASE/dist/e4.9/spring-tool-suite-3.9.9.RELEASE-e4.9.0-win32.zip. But I would strongly recommend to update to a more up-to-date version on a 64bit environment, if possible.

Comment: Thank you Andy and Martin your answers were really helpful. STS 3.9.9 is working good in my system.